# jquery - next() won't work but siblings() will

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a form which has multiple sections with 'yes/no' radio buttons and a textarea. When the page loads, the textareas are disabled and all the 'no' radio buttons are checked by default. I'm trying to get it so that once the user selects a 'yes' radio button, the disabled attribute is removed from the relevant textarea.

I'm trying to this using next('textarea'), but this doesn't seem to work. What's weird is that siblings does work (using the same selector) but obviously it targets all the textareas rather than just the relevant one.

Any ideas?

Here's my code (simplified):

```
<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="rdo" />Yes
<input type="radio" value="No" name="rdo" checked/>No
<br />
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" disabled></textarea>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":radio[value=Yes]").click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('checked','true')) {
            $(this).next('textarea').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AThomas92/Ry2fX/

Cheers,

Ash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated by jQuery doc :

> ## .next()
>
> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

So the next of `$(":radio[value=Yes]")` is input no.

Here 2 other options (1 as been already stated) :

- [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)
- [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: Ahhhh, that explains it, I misread it originally and thought it would find the next instance of that selector. I'm confused as to why my question was downvoted though?

Comment: @Godge Yes, probably downvoted as a *"lack of research effort"*.

Comment: Fair enough I guess :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yeah that is an obvious result, since `.next('textarea')` will only search for the next sibling immediately after to the current element with the supplied selector. But unlike `.next()`, `.siblings()` will search for all the siblings around the current element by the supplied selector and return the matched one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the input so it can work

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="rdo" />Yes
   <input type="radio" value="No" name="rdo" checked/>No
   <br />
   <textarea rows="4" cols="50" disabled></textarea>
</div>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":radio[value=Yes]").click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('checked','true')) {
            $('textarea', $(this).parent()).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```